# Can't make Ajax work with Struts/Spring

Tags: java, ajax, spring, jsp, struts

I'm trying to make Ajax work with a simple WebApp using Struts and Spring, so I can load a .jsp inside a div tag on another .jsp, but I keep getting a "Resource not found" error. I've looked all over the web but still can't figure it out.

Here's my code:

**struts-config.xml**

```
<global-exceptions>
</global-exceptions>
<global-forwards></global-forwards>

<action-mappings>
    <action path="/ajax" input="/index.jsp" type="org.springframework.web.struts.DelegatingActionProxy">
        <forward name="success" path="/contenido.jsp" />
    </action>

</action-mappings>

<plug-in className="org.springframework.web.struts.ContextLoaderPlugIn">
         <set-property property="contextConfigLocation"
            value="/WEB-INF/classes/spring/ApplicationContext.xml"/>
</plug-in>
```

**ApplicationContext.xml**

```
<!-- Actions Classes -->
<bean name="/ajax" class="com.ajax.prueba.action.AjaxAction"> </bean>
```

**AjaxAction.java**

```
public class AjaxAction extends Action {

    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {

        return mapping.findForward("success");
    }
}
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" %>
<%@taglib prefix="html" uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Ajax Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/js/general.js"/>"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>This is an Ajax Test</h1>
        <html:link  href="#" onclick="loadContent()" >Show Message</html:link>

        <div id="content"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

**contenido.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

Ajax is working!
```

**general.js**

```
var xmlhttp;

function loadContent()
{

 xmlhttp=GetXmlHttpObject();

  if (xmlhttp==null)
  {
   alert ("Your browser does not support Ajax HTTP");
   return;
  }

    var url="/ajax.do";

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=getOutput;
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}

function getOutput()
{
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
  {
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
}

function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
       return new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    if (window.ActiveXObject)
    {
      return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
 return null;
}
```

The index.jsp is loading just fine, but when I click on the "Show message" link, I get the 404 from the Apache server:

> type Status report
>
> message /ajax.do
>
> description The requested resource (/ajax.do) is not available.

Sorry if it's too long. This is just a small app to test Ajax and then use it on another big application I'm working on (that I also getting the same problem).

Any idea what the problem might be? Am I thinking the redirection with Struts the wrong way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the full path of the action:

```
    url='http:\\localhost:8080\'+appName+'\ajax.do'
```